# Is measure theory only for integrals?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, applications

I am trying to self-study probabilistic measure theory after completing my undergrad degree, and I am curious if there are more interesting applications of measure theory aside from Lebesgue integration ? It seems like (correct me if I am wrong here) measure on its own is a rich field before delving in integration of measurable functions.

Comment: What do you consider "not integration"? The measure of a set is the integral of the corresponding indicator function.

Comment: One immediate example that comes to mind are Hausdorff measures which can be used to measure the (non-integer) dimension of fractals.

Comment: A measure is how we can measure a set in general case, not only for real numbers, but the integral gives the flexibility to imagine that there is a certain "density" on the set - this is the integrand. If the integrand function, i.e. density, is unit, then the integral is just a measure.

Comment: So basically integral and measure are the same(or equivalent) concept(s) ?
@zkutch

Comment: "basically" is very subjective word,  
@Pat - in mathematics I prefer to say, that integral is based on measure. It will be funny theory, if someone created reverse - it will be same as to create volume from mass. Now we based mass (integral) on volume (measure).

Comment: Ergodic Theory is based on measure theory.  See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory

Answer (score 4):

I would propose that the construction of measures itself can be a highly non-trivial task in measure theory, yet it is the very foundation of it.

Think of what a measure is: It is a non-negative set-function $\mu$ from some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$. This means, to define a measure we need to assign to every set $A\in\mathcal F$ a value $\mu(A)\in[0,\infty]$. But often times the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ will be very large and involve very complicated sets (for example [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set#Measure_and_probability) in the real line). Are we really going to find some nice "formula" to define $\mu(A)$ for every possible $A\in\mathcal F$? Probably not...

This is why extension Theorems like [Caratheodory's Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_extension_theorem) are so vital: They allow us to uniquely define measures on a "complicated" $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ by only defining it on some "simpler" generating set $\mathcal C\subset \mathcal F$. This would be one example of an important piece of measure theory that is "independent" of integration.

To give another interesting example from Probability Theory, where we are not so much concerned about **integration** with respect to a probability measure, but rather constructing a probability measure in the first place: Consider the theory of Stochastic Processes. Often times we want the paths of such a process to be continuous (or at least cádlág), which means we are trying to construct some probability measure on the set of continuous functions $C$ (or the set of cádlág functions $D$). But how would one even try to do this? Note that now our $\sigma$-algebra consists of "function sets", i.e. sets $A\subseteq C$.

The most intuitive way to understand a stochastic process is to not look at its law over $C$, but rather at the laws of the finite-dimensional projections of it. This means, one may try to construct a stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}\in C$ by considering the finite-dimensional projections  $(X_{t_1},\dots,X_{t_k})$ for various $t_1<\dots<t_k\in[0,\infty)$ and hope to "extend" the collection of their distributions on $\mathbb R^k$ to a distribution on $C$. Here, extension Theorems like [Kolmogorov's Extension Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem) together with [Kolmogorov's Continuity Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem) provide a way to do this.

Again, in the theory of stochastic processes we may not even be interested in integrating against a measure $\mu$ on $C$ (though there are certainly areas of Stochastic Analysis where this is done) but rather constructing such measures and analyzing them in some way, e.g. studying [Weak Convergence on $C$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243572/how-to-understand-the-definition-of-weak-convergence-of-stochastic-processes). While weak convergence *can* be understood via integrationg w.r.t. bounded continuous function (à la Portmanteau), this approach is completely intractable for stochastic processes, hence one looks for other criterions of weak convergence, see e.g. [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/15-070j-advanced-stochastic-processes-fall-2013/47c18ebc5d68ab0e2fdb9e39e1a4b0ac_MIT15_070JF13_Lec21.pdf) for an overview for continuous processes and [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/9781118150672.app2) for an overview for cádlág processes.

Comment: *But often times the* $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ *will be very large and involve very complicated sets (for example Cantor set in the real line).* -- Since the Cantor set is closed (complement of an open set; countable intersection of open sets), it's VERY LOW for complexity in the transfinite hierarchy of elements in a $\sigma$-algebra -- level $0$ or $1,$ depending on how one begins enumerating the levels, out of $\omega_1$-many levels. More complicated are sets at various [large number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_numbers) levels, **(continued)**

Comment: and even more complicated sets are at various large countable ordinal levels (see [1](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/06/29/large-countable-ordinals-part-1/) and [2](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/07/04/large-countable-ordinals-part-2/) and [3](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2016/07/07/large-countable-ordinals-part-3/)). That said, there are different ways of measuring complicated'ness, and so while both the Cantor set and the Mandelbrot set are closed sets, each can certainly be considered to be fairly complicated sets.